# Django paypal ipn standard payer address

Tags: django, django-paypal

I am using the DCramer fork of django-paypal: https://github.com/dcramer/django-paypal

I am using IPN standard

What I would like to do is get the payer (customer) address from the IPN. I can see from the paypal docs this info is sent with an IPN and from looking through django-paypal there are fields in the database to store this data.  However this data is not being stored in the paypal_ipn model provided by django-paypal.  I have also inspected the ipn_obj in the signals and all the fields for this data are blank there too.

Can anyone shed any light on how I might be able to get the payer address?

If it helps I'm using the signals from the example:

```
    #Paypal signals
    from paypal.standard.ipn.signals import payment_was_successful
    import datetime

    #Signal for paypal confirmation
    def show_me_the_money(sender, **kwargs):
        ipn_obj = sender

        # Undertake some action depending upon `ipn_obj`.

    payment_was_successful.connect(show_me_the_money)
```

EDIT:

The dump of the ipn_obj suggested by scytale below produces this for the relevant fields:

```
    address_city\t(<type 'unicode'>)\t: 
    address_country\t(<type 'unicode'>)\t: 
    address_country_code\t(<type 'unicode'>)\t: 
    address_name\t(<type 'unicode'>)\t: 
    address_state\t(<type 'unicode'>)\t: 
    address_status\t(<type 'unicode'>)\t: 
    address_street\t(<type 'unicode'>)\t: 
    address_zip\t(<type 'unicode'>)\t:
```

There are loads of other fields too, if you need the data from those let me know and I'll paste them here.

Comment: dump out the data in ipn_obj - `for key in sorted(ipn_obj.__dict__.iterkeys()): print "  %s\t(%s)\t: %s\n" % (key, type(ipn_obj.__dict__[key]), ipn_obj.__dict__[key])`

Comment: @scytale I have edited the question to include the dump of the address fields produced by the code you provided, thank you.

Comment: ok that looks all wrong - for a start remove all occurrences of '\t' and '\n' from the print statement (in my code that I copied this from I use `file.write()` instead of `print` so '\t' outputs a tab. then try again. So far it looks like all the address fields are empty strings.

Comment: This same issue showed for me.Am not able to save any data in database.Did you solve the issue,if please help me?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're not getting the address information in the first place. You can ask paypal to send the customer's address from their paypal account or you can get the address from the customer on your site and include the data in the paypal button HTML - paypal then sends this information back to you in the IPN data. See the [Forms Basics guide](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_html_formbasics#id08A6F0SJ04Y) for more details.

Since you're using django-paypal (right?) you can include this data in the paypal button simply by adding fields to the dict of initial values you pass to `PayPalPaymentsForm` as described in the django-paypal [docs](https://github.com/tomscytale/django-paypal#using-paypal-payments-standard-ipn).

Comment: So I take it that I cannot retrieve the address which the user has stored at paypal.com and entered when creating their account there?

I've had a look at the PayPalPaymentsForm in paypal/standard/forms.py but it does not to appear to accept values for payer address etc.  I tried passing the variables to the form anyway and it did not complain but I can see in the resultant HTML that they are not included in the button.

Comment: yes you can use the address that paypal has stored. However it is not guaranteed to have this info and there are many use cases to consider. Read the relevant section of the "Forms Basics" that I posted to before and also read https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_html_Appx_BillingShippingAddress  If you have passed the relevant data to the form but it is not appearing in the button HTML then please display the code you are using to pass in those values.